# Why does the volatge drop is huge once a load is connected to a generator?

Tags: power, voltage, transformer, generator

At no load condition the generated voltage at transformer secondary output is 140 V ac. When a 60W resistive load is connected the voltage drops to 27 V ac. The pmg generator rating is 1 KW 415 V and transformer rating is 415/230 Vac 1 Kva. Why does the voltage drops so much and what would be the reason behind this scenario?

Comment: Does rotational speed also lower?

Comment: Torque applied is maintain at constant for both scenario. But during the load condition there is a significant drop in rotation speed. It seems as the pmg got heavier. So to answer your question, yes the rotation speed is lower during load condition. @Andyaka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Torque applied is maintain at constant for both scenario. But during
>   the load condition there is a significant drop in rotation speed.

If input torque is held constant then you are fashioning a constant current generator and not a constant voltage generator. Input mechanical speed would need to be held constant to produce a "near-enough" constant output voltage.

Mechanical power in = \$2\pi n T\$ where n is speed (rev/sec) and T is torque. You have kept T constant but allowed n to fall therefore the mechanical power into the generator has fallen just when you wanted power to increase!